# Need to re-render component after state is set to true

Tags: reactjs

In my react app, I have a page that allows the user to "add" exercises to a personal list. The option to add an exercise is included in one "page" and the ability to see added exercises is view in a other. [Side by side showing the two pages, notice 'Your Exercises' is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAAC8.png). What I am trying to do is display these selected exercises. The exercises themselves are loaded via mapping function, from an array of objects. each object has a "selected" field and are set as "false" by default. My "add" button in the exercises page changes the state value of each component to "true", so now what I want to do is get these "true" values and render them on the page where it should show your exercises.

```js
//Render your exercises
import React from "react";
import ExListItem from "./ExListItem";
// import selectedExercises from "../../../selectedExercises";
import exercises from  "../../../exercises";

const selectedExerciseList = exercises
  .filter(function (item) {
    return item.selected === true;
  })
  .map(function ({name, reps}) {
    return {name, reps};
  });
// MAP HERE
function createSelectedExercises(exercises) {
  return <ExListItem name={exercises.name} reps={exercises.reps} />;
}
function ExerciseList() {
  return (
    <ul data-tag="channelList" id="exercise-list" class="list-group mb-3">
      {selectedExerciseList.map(createSelectedExercises)}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default ExerciseList;
```

Shouldnt this map the exercises?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use React state to accomplish this! You can do so with the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Component = () => {
   const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
      setExercises(exerciseFilterFunction(exercises)) // this will cause the re-render
   }, [])

   return (
      <div>{exercises.map(e => <div>{e.name}</div>)}</div>
   )
}
```

Comment: I should've also mentioned that I have a button on a separate page (shows your exercises) that allows you to refresh this list, calling the rerender. How would I try your code out in a button click?

Comment: Ah okay! Any event can cause a re-render as long as you call the setExercises() function. So in your case, you would do something like <button onClick={someEvent}>Button</button> and then const someEvent = () => {setExercises(someNewExercisesArray)}

Comment: Thank you! This should point me in the right direction. I noticed that on page switch/refresh, my state does not save, so I have managed to use useEffect to save it.

Comment: Awesome, sounds good! Glad it helped :)